# comparing the contents of more than three files in linux

Tags: linux

In Linux
to compare the contents of two text files or three I've **diff** & **diff3** command.

But what if I
need to compare **more than 3 files** at a time??

Comment: Why are you asking? Can some of the files be identical to others?

Comment: @Basile, I've to compare 5 text files containing data send by client. I need to know compare those files, I have gone with google but found diff3 which can compare only 3 files. so how to compare more than that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a simple script to compare all the files that you want.

Example:

In directory that contains all files

```
for i in `ls | grep -v [file_want_compare]` ; do diff [file_want_compare] $i; done
```